# Find crossing lines in drawing engine

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3

i am working on a little multimedia - project in which the user, amongst other things, can draw shapes on a canvas (2d) by connecting points with a line.
but i need to prohibit the user from crossing lines.

what i am looking for would be a small algorithm that can find intersecting lines.
the project is done in AS3/Flash but i guess the answer would be universal.

anyone can give me a clue?

thanks

Comment: I have a feeling that said algorithm won't be anything 'small' :(

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example in Java but I think you can easily adapt to AS3 :

```
public static boolean intersects(double ax, double ay, double bx, double by,
        double cx, double cy, double dx, double dy) {
    double denum = ((bx-ax)*(dy-cy)-(by-ay)*(dx-cx));
    if (denum == 0) return false; // parallel segments
    double r = ((ay-cy)*(dx-cx)-(ax-cx)*(dy-cy)) / denum;
    double s = 
            ((ay-cy)*(bx-ax)-(ax-cx)*(by-ay)) / denum;
    return 0<=r && r<=1 && 0<=s && s<=1;
}
```

It should return true if the segments [AB] and [CD] intersect.
You can find reference [here](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/graphics/algorithms-faq/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods `Point`, `hitTest`, `hitTestObject` or `hitTestPoint`. I don't know if Super Chafouin's answer is helpful, but I believe that the code looks quite different in AS3 though.

To explain what they mean, I'll quote *Aaron Beall* from [actionscript.org](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=272790), giving a nice explanation:

> **hitTestObject** checks the bounding box rectangle of two display
>   objects. It always checks rectangle-vs-rectangle.
>
> **hitTestPoint** checks a point (x,y) against a display object:
>   - With shapeFlag true it checks point-vs-shape
>   - With shapeFlag false it checks point-vs-rectangle
>
> BitmapData/**hitTest** checks a bitmap against a point, rectangle, or
>   other bitmapdata. Using a check of bitmapdata-vs-bitmapdata means you
>   can perform alpha channel based shape-vs-shape checks. See here:
>   [http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/200...ion-detection/](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/)
>
> (Also, not to nitpick but just to make sure you understand, neither
>   hitTestObject or hitTestPoint are "triggered" -- you must manually
>   call them when you want to check something.)

Asking for a whole algorithm is quite something, it depends on your app too.

See for more examples and documentation **[here](http://help.adobe.com/nl_NL/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7dca.html)**, **[here](http://community.adobe.com/help/search.html?q=hittest&hl=nl_NL&lr=nl_NL&l=flash_product_adobelr&requiredfields=book%3aActionScript%25C2%25A03%252E0%2520voor%2520Flash%2520programmeren&self=1&filter=0)**

I hope this will help!

Comment: checking for line/line collisions is perfect.
i ended up using a modified verion of the code i found at http://keith-hair.net/blog/2008/08/04/find-intersection-point-of-two-lines-in-as3/ and Super Chafouins code. cheers and thanks again!